# Rails to_param custom route not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

In Rails 3.2.2, I want to setup custom URLs (using State 2 digit :abbr, instead of the default by :id)

Reading google results and stackoverflow pages, I've come up with this:

## Routes

```
match 'cars/:abbr' => 'states#show', :as => 'state_abbr'
```

## Model

```
def to_param
  abbr
end
```

## Controller

```
@state = State.find_by_abbr(params[:id])
```

The state#show page is throwing out errors (undefined method `fullname' for nil:NilClass), because the routing does not seem to be finding the *abbr* in the model.

Running *rake routes*, I get:

```
 root  /                    states#index
 state_abbr  /cars/:abbr(.:format) states#show
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure the errors aren't due to `find_by_abbr(params[:id])` ? Check to see what params is throwing out - with those routes you should see `:abbr` (maybe `:state_abbr`) and not `:id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `params[:abbr]` not `params[:id]`. If you want to use `:id` change your route to be `'cars/:id'` instead of `'cars/:abbr'`

Comment: I tried `@state = State.find_by_abbr(params[:abbr])` but the same error is showing up

undefined method `fullname' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Then it sounds like your find_by_abbr is not finding the item you're looking for. Did you double check that your database as an entry in the states table with an abbr entry that you're looking up?

Comment: You can also `p params` in your controller before doing the lookup to see if it has the `:abbr` value you're expecting.

Comment: ahh, so the issue was that in my DB, the state name was all caps ("CA"), whereas i was putting in 'ca' as the route.